# I want to increase total by one if the topic already exist else do normal insert

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE count_demo
(
    topic VARCHAR primary key,
    total integer
)
```

Query

```
INSERT INTO count_demo (topic, total) 
VALUES ('topic1', 0) 
    ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET total = total + 1
```

Problem

> Error: column reference total is ambiguous

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO count_demo (topic, total)
VALUES ('topic1', 0) 
ON CONFLICT (topic) 
DO 
   UPDATE SET total = count_demo.total + 1;
```

Ref: [Upsert](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161127/column-reference-is-ambiguous-when-upserting-element-into-table)

Comment: Good answer because it should be pointed out that the affected column (here "topic") must be named instead of just writing ON CONFLICT DO...

Answer (score 0):

Below query worked for me:

```
INSERT INTO count_demo (topic, total) 
VALUES ('topic1', 0) 
    ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET total = count_demo.total + 1
```